# a ready only UITextView in a table view cell blocks selection

Tags: ios, swift

My table view cell has a UITextView that presents read only text. The reason I am using a text view instead of a UILabel is to support the native copy/share menu on long press. My problem is the row containing the cell should also respond to tap (didSelect) and navigate to another scree. Tapping anywhere on the cell outside the text view works, but tapping the text view does not fire a didSelect callback in the table view. For illustration, the text view in question is the one with the text "Oleg Sherman" in the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: did you check if user interaction is enabled for the cell?

Comment: this will also prevent the copy menu from showing in long press, which is why I am using a text view and not a label

Answer (score 1):

Disabling user interaction on the text view will make any touches pass through it to it's parent view.

```
myTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: yes but this will also prevent the copy menu from showing in long press, which is why I am using a text view and not a label

Comment: You mean to highlight the text directly?  Put a long press gesture recognizer on the cell itself that gives some kind of context menu to copy the cell's displayed text, that's how Apple handles it.  https://imgur.com/a/F4NiE9o

Comment: This would not be good enough. I can put a menu myself for copy but I cannot do the crosshairs text selection. I really do need to use that UITextView

Comment: In that case I think you will have to put a gesture recognizer on the text view and then call the table view's didSelectRowAt with the index path of the text view's parent cell.

Comment: thanks clawesome, right on the spot. I implemented it based on your idea and it works.